# Find out where function is unfiormly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x)=\sin(\ln x)$ for $x>0$

find such $a,b,c,d>0$ where $f(x)$ is:

uniformly continuous at intervals $(0,a], [b,+\infty)$

and Lipschitz at $(0,c]$ , $[d,+\infty)$

Comment: Hints: 1. A differentiable function with bounded derivative on some interval $I$ is Lipschitz, hence uniformly continuous, in $I$. (This is the content of science's answer.) 2. A continuous function on a bounded open interval $(a, b)$ is uniformly continuous in $(a, b)$ if and only if there exists a continuous extension to the closed interval $[a, b]$. (That isn't obvious, but should help you determine the right answer.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Check Mean value theorem.

Comment: but didn't it works for Lipschitz condition ? I mean can't be other uniformly cont. intervals where $f(x)$ isn't  Lipschitz ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If f is differentiable on an open subset $U$, then:
$$ f' \text{ is bounded on } U \Leftrightarrow f \text{ is Lipschitz on } U$$